# Pandas - convert cumulative value to actual value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Let's say my dataframe looks something like this:

```
date,site,country_code,kind,ID,rank,votes,sessions,avg_score,count
2017-03-20,website1,US,0,84,226,0.0,15.0,3.370812,53.0
2017-03-21,website1,US,0,84,214,0.0,15.0,3.370812,53.0
2017-03-22,website1,US,0,84,226,0.0,16.0,3.370812,53.0
2017-03-23,website1,US,0,84,234,0.0,16.0,3.369048,54.0
2017-03-24,website1,US,0,84,226,0.0,16.0,3.369048,54.0
2017-03-25,website1,US,0,84,212,0.0,16.0,3.369048,54.0
2017-03-26,website1,US,0,84,228,0.0,16.0,3.369048,54.0
2017-02-15,website2,AU,1,91,144,4.0,148.0,4.727272,521.0
2017-02-16,website2,AU,1,91,144,3.0,147.0,4.727272,524.0
2017-02-17,website2,AU,1,91,100,4.0,148.0,4.727272,524.0
2017-02-18,website2,AU,1,91,118,6.0,149.0,4.727272,527.0
2017-02-19,website2,AU,1,91,114,4.0,151.0,4.727272,529.0
```

The `count` column at the very end is a cumulative count.
What I need to do is find the actual count for a particular 
date+site+country+kind+ID tuple, which would result in:

```
date,site,country_code,kind,ID,rank,votes,sessions,avg_score,count
2017-03-20,website1,US,0,84,226,0.0,15.0,3.370812,0.0
2017-03-21,website1,US,0,84,214,0.0,15.0,3.370812,0.0
2017-03-22,website1,US,0,84,226,0.0,16.0,3.370812,0.0
2017-03-23,website1,US,0,84,234,0.0,16.0,3.369048,1.0
2017-03-24,website1,US,0,84,226,0.0,16.0,3.369048,0.0
2017-03-25,website1,US,0,84,212,0.0,16.0,3.369048,0.0
2017-03-26,website1,US,0,84,228,0.0,16.0,3.369048,0.0
2017-02-15,website2,AU,1,91,144,4.0,148.0,4.727272,0.0
2017-02-16,website2,AU,1,91,144,3.0,147.0,4.727272,3.0
2017-02-17,website2,AU,1,91,100,4.0,148.0,4.727272,0.0
2017-02-18,website2,AU,1,91,118,6.0,149.0,4.727272,3.0
2017-02-19,website2,AU,1,91,114,4.0,151.0,4.727272,2.0
```

I know this would involve a `groupby` call but I have no idea what to do beyond that. Let's assume that the very first instance of the tuple would have a count of `0`.
Any help would awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `diff`, the inverse of `cumsum`.

```
cols = ['site', 'country_code', 'kind', 'ID']
df['count'] = df.groupby(cols)['count'].diff().fillna(0)

print(df['count'])
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     1.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     3.0
9     0.0
10    3.0
11    2.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

Thanks to MaxU for pointing out the error!

Comment: Thanks but that will result in a value of `467` for the tuple `(2017-02-15,website2,AU,1,91)` whereas it should be 0

Comment: I think OP want's something like: `df.groupby('site')['count'].diff().fillna(0)`

Comment: @Craig With help from MaxU, I was able to figure out what you wanted. See my edit.

Comment: Great thanks @coldspeed - I ended up having to group by `[site,country_code,kind,ID]`, but this is exactly what I was looking for!